# How to add datagridview column header text as combobox items, C#..?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a datagridview with multiple columns in form1 and my form2 contains number of comboboxs. Here, i like to add (form1) datagridview columns header text as (form2) combobox items.

already i tried this in form2,

```
try
{
  Form1 F1 = new Form1();

  comboBox1.Items.Add(F1.dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText);
  comboBox1.Items.Add(F1.dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText);
  comboBox1.Items.Add(F1.dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText);
  comboBox1.Items.Add(F1.dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText);
  comboBox1.Items.Add(F1.dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText);
  comboBox1.Items.Add(F1.dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText);
}
catch{}
```

but no use.. can anyone help regarding my request.

Answer (score 1):

yeah this can be done by changing the access modifier of the DataGridView from Private to Public i have done it practically and it works

```
    public System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;// at your form1
```

[image]

Comment: I think it's a bad practice to change whole class/form access modifier. It may relay on your needs but normally I would try avoiding that.

Answer (score 0):

One approach (using capsulation) is to add this function to your `F1`form:

```
public string GetDGVHeaderText(int index)
{
    if (index < dataGridView1.ColumnCount)
    {
        return dataGridView1.Columns[index].HeaderText;
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

(Note that I return empty string when invalid index given, you can alter this to fit your needs)

And change the constructor in `F2` to:

```
public F2(F1 f1Ref)
```

Now you can store a reference to your second form in `F2` or use it in the constructor body.

For example:

```
public F2(F1 f1Ref)
{ 
    InitializeComponent();

    comboBox1.Items.Add(f1Ref.GetDGVHeaderText(0));
    comboBox2.Items.Add(f1Ref.GetDGVHeaderText(1));
}
```